Json list to flow collection not collecting
First time typing here because this is driving me insane... I've been trying to get a json parsed record collection to use in flow. Apex class does get the information only from the first json record from the list and leaves the rest. Still am a amateur in json coding and I would gladly appreciate the help for this issue.
Apex code snippet (ask if more code info is needed) that maps the output. I am unsure how to properly loop it:
public static FlowOutputParameters assignOutput(){
        FlowOutputParameters output = new FlowOutputParameters();
        
        integer i = 0;
        Map<String, object> designDetails = (Map<String,object>) jsonResponse;
        if(designDetails == null) return null;
        
        originCountry = (string) designDetails.get('RegistrationOfficeCode');
        if (countryCode != null) originCountry = countryCode;

        Map<String, object> designDetailsReg = (Map<String,object>) parseToObject(designDetailKeys(), i);
        
        MarkifyResponse design = new MarkifyResponse();

        design.applicationNumber = (string) designDetails.get('DesignApplicationNumber');
        design.applicationDate = parseDate((string) designDetails.get('DesignApplicationDate'));
        design.registrationNumber = (string) designDetailsReg.get('RegistrationNumber');
        design.registrationDate = parseDate((string) designDetailsReg.get('RegistrationDate'));
        design.registrationOfficeCode = (string) designDetails.get('RegistrationOfficeCode');
        design.publicationDate = (string) designDetailsReg.get('PublicationDate');
        design.markVerbalElementText = (string) designDetailsReg.get('DesignTitle');
        design.statusMsg = (string) designDetails.get('MarkifyDesignCurrentStatusCode');
        
        list<MarkifyResponse> designs = new list<MarkifyResponse>();
        designs.add(design);
        output.records = designs;
        return output;
    }

 public static List<string> designKeys(){
        return new List<string> {'response', 'DesignTransactionBody', 'TransactionContentDetails', 'TransactionData', 'DesignDetails', 'DesignApplication'};
    }



Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Please edit your post to show an example of the JSON format you are trying to build.  The best way to work with JSON in Apex is to use the JSON class methods serialize and deserialize.
